# Расширение Chrome - как показать popup программно?

Tags: google-chrome, chrome-extension, chrome-app

Моя задача:
При появлении новых данных - показать popup (который по умолчанию появляется по клику на иконку расширения) с этими данными.

Как можно popup показать программно, из кода расширения?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Программно такая возможность отсуствует.

Однако, чтобы информировать пользователя о каком-то событие, вы можете воспользоваться одним из вариантов:

1. [chrome.notifications API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/notifications);
2. Добавив на страницу элемент с абсолютным позиционирование через content-script (*так делает например Pocket*);
3. Активировать значок [pageAction](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageAction).